# Image FILL logic such as "Stretch.Uniform" of WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image-scaling

I'm looking out for an Image FILL logic to apply in my console application, which generates TIFF file. I have image container dimension as **1200 * 1800** pixel.

Have applied below logic to get resize the image to fit in this dimension, but this logic applies the FIT part and not FILL part of it.

If I have image dimension as **1200 * 1600** then I get blank space at below, and if I try to fit the image, in container then it stretch's the image and image doesn't look good. Image above **1200 * 1600** does fits well.

I'm looking for logic similar to "**Stretch.Uniform**"  of WPF application which fills the image uni-formally without loosing the image actual view.

```
private static Dimension getScaledDimension(Dimension imgSize, Dimension boundary)
{

    int original_width = imgSize.width;
    int original_height = imgSize.height;
    int bound_width = boundary.width;
    int bound_height = boundary.height;
    int new_width = original_width;
    int new_height = original_height;

    // first check if we need to scale width. 
    if (original_width > bound_width)  
    {
        //scale width to fit
        new_width = bound_width;
        //scale height to maintain aspect ratio
        new_height = (new_width * original_height) / original_width;
    }


    // then check if we need to scale even with the new height. 
    if (new_height > bound_height)
    {
        //scale height to fit instead
        new_height = bound_height;
        //scale width to maintain aspect ratio
        new_width = (new_height * original_width) / original_height;
    }

    return new Dimension { height = new_height, width = new_width };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: Principle image]

Check the aspect ratio of 2 rectangles to decide which property to fit.

```
private static Dimension getScaledDimension(Dimension imgSize, Dimension boundary)
{
    int original_width = imgSize.width;
    int original_height = imgSize.height;
    int bound_width = boundary.width;
    int bound_height = boundary.height;

    double original_aspect = (double)original_width / original_height;
    double bound_aspect = (double)bound_width / bound_height;

    //original size is wider than boundary, fit boundary width
    if(original_aspect > bound_aspect)
    {
        return new Dimension
        {
            width = boundary.width,
            height = (int)Math.Round(boundary.width / original_aspect)
        };
    }

    //original size is taller than boundary, fit boundary height
    else
    {
        return new Dimension
        {
            height = boundary.height,
            width = (int)Math.Round(boundary.height * original_aspect)
        };
    }
}
```